# Several File in java IO stream

Tags: java, io

server  send several files through a single outputstream, when the client receive the byte[], how does it  extract the files? Is there any marks in the bytes ? for example ,EOF? '\r\n', or  else ? it seems that java basic IO,even the NIO both can not do that.
    I　think sending several files through a single IO channel, we should insert some special characters to divide the bytes. FYI.

Comment: Is this a question? Obviously if you want to send multiple entities you need to differentiate between the entities.

Comment: I think there is a very low probability to generate collision , the differentiate we inserted with the normal bytes, for example, a jpeg file, we use 'ffff' to distinct the next jpg file, but maybe 'ffff' is part of the jpg file.

Comment: I think there's a relatively *high* probability of a "collision", particularly if you're sending binary data. That's why, for example, HTTP multiparts use a GUID between entities. IMO better to just zip up the files and send over in a known multi-part format. But I'm still unclear on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking a low level function if you wrap your stream in a multi-part or zip (no compression is an option) stream you won't have to re-implement markers.